# Cinemachine - Change TrackedDolly Path from CinemachineVirtualCamera from code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have added Cinemachine to my main camera.
Then, I added Dolly Camera and Dolly Track. I can use my dolly track to show my camera animation perfectly.

**Problem:**
Now, I want to have multiple dolly tracks with different animations. So I added new Dolly track with another animation.

I can see my new animation perfectly.
Now, I tried to switch between these two Dolly Tracks from code.
I cannot access that Tracked Path.

On looking at : [CinemachineVirtualCamera class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.1/api/Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera.html) I see no property to set Dolly Track from code.

**QUESTIONS:**
I think there should be the way to switch between Dolly Tracks from code. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void CameraSomeFunc(){

    cvCamera = _curentCamera.GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
    track = cvCamera.GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachineTrackedDolly>();

    pathLength = track.m_Path.PathLength;
    track.m_PathOffset = Vector3.zero;
    
    track.m_PathPosition += speed;
}
```